# Open file in a specific folder

Tags: file-io, path, fortran

I want to open a file located in "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/Reliability/Job-M1/input_files".
My code looks like:

```
    character :: JobName, JobDir, JobInpFol
    JobName="Job-M1"
    JobDir="/Reliability/" // JobName
    JobInpFol=JobDir // "/input_files/"
    OPEN(20, FILE="C:/Abaqus_JOBS" // JobInpFol // 
 1  "failureUEL.txt", action="write",status="replace")
```

However fortran opens the file in "C:/Abaqus_JOBS".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is your code, then `JobName`, `JobDir`, and `JobInpFol` are all characters with length 1 (you can test this by adding `print *,len(JobName), len(JobDir), len(JobInpFol)` in your code. So your open line is really seeing the `/` in `"/Reliability/"`.

You want something like `character(len=30) :: JobName, JobDir, JobInpFol` and then use `trim(adjustl(JobName))` to eliminate white spaces.

Comment: adjustl is superfluous here